# django-import-export : import not working

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am trying to populate my database with `.csv` files with `django-import-export` module but I keep running in this error

`Line number: 1 - maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object 43, Sicilian, L, 0, 1,7, 45.7`
whenever I try to populate my `Pizza` model through the admin UI.

Here is my CSV

[image: csv file]

`admin.py`

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin

from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

from .models import Topping, Pizza, Sub, Pasta, Salad, Dinner


class PizzaAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(PizzaAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        form.instance.toppings.add(Topping.objects.get(name='Cheese'))

@admin.register(Sub)
class SubAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Topping)
admin.site.register(Pizza, PizzaAdmin)
# admin.site.register(Sub)
admin.site.register(Pasta)
admin.site.register(Salad)
admin.site.register(Dinner)
```

`models.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Create your models here.


class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return(f"{self.name}")


class Pizza(models.Model):
    PIZZA_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )

    pizza_type = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    pizza_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PIZZA_SIZES)
    qty_toppings = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(3)], default=0)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, related_name='pizzas', blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(help_text="Price in $")


    def __str__(self):
        return f"Size: {self.get_pizza_size_display()}, Type: {self.pizza_type}, Number of Toppings: {self.qty_toppings},  Price: {self.price}, Toppings: {self.toppings.in_bulk()}"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if 'toppings' not in kwargs:
        # kwargs.setdefault('force_insert', True)
        # kwargs.setdefault('force_update', True)
        super(Pizza, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.toppings.add(Topping.objects.get(name='Cheese'))
        # kwargs.setdefault('toppings', Topping.objects.get(name='Cheese'))


class Sub(models.Model):
    SUBS_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )

    subs_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SUBS_SIZES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    price = models.IntegerField(help_text="Price in $")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, {self.get_subs_size_display()} : {self.price}"

class Pasta(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    price = models.IntegerField(help_text="Price in $")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} : {self.price}"


class Salad(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    price = models.IntegerField(help_text="Price in $")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} : {self.price}"


class Dinner(models.Model):
    DINNER_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )

    dinner_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DINNER_SIZES)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    price = models.IntegerField(help_text="Price in $")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, {self.get_dinner_size_display()} : {self.price}"


class Euser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return(f"{self.id}")


class ShoppingCart(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    pizzas = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza)
    subs = models.ManyToManyField(Sub)
    pastas = models.ManyToManyField(Pasta)
    dinners = models.ManyToManyField(Dinner)

    number_of_articles = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return(f"{self.user}'s cart")

@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def create_user_cart(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ShoppingCart.objects.create(user=instance)




# @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
# def create_user_cart(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
#     if created:
#         ShoppingCart.objects.create(user=instance)

# @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
# def save_user_cart(sender, instance, **kwargs): 
#    instance.shoppingcart.save()
```

FYI: Used pandas to convert this same `.csv` to a `.json`, and I got `KeyError encountered while trying to read file: pizza_sicilian.json`

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Two `topings` (1,7) where the delimiter is comma? Try first to remove second toping from 43 and 38 lines and see if it will work.

Comment: ```Line number: 1 - maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
43, Sicilian, L, 0, 1, 45.7```

Got same error

Comment: so I tried to add a ```Pizza``` with an ```id``` that was already taken, and it managed to update the row in the database, but if I either empty the ```id``` column or put random ```id's``` that are not taken, it gives me this recursive error

Comment: This must be something in `Pizza` save method. I guess this line `self.toppings.add(Topping.objects.get(name='Cheese'))`  - isn't save called after using `add`? That's will explain the error.

Comment: I don't think it is related to the ```Pizza's save method``` as I commented both the ```save``` method on the ```admin.py``` and on the ```models.py```, and still, I get the same error

I did try to ```import``` a ```.csv``` for the ```Sub``` model, and it passed.

I am thinking of some internal error related to ```m2m``` with the ```Topping``` model ..

Answer (score 1):

i have faced the same issue
i would rather suggest you

```
in admin .py
@admin.register(Sub)
class SubAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display=["pizza","other objects in model"]
    pass
```

list_display is a default function an the items should be in a list ...
this solved my issue , i think it will help many viewers!
Thnak you!